# Is it possible to create a Nuget package of ASP.NET Website?

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package, ashx

I have an old ASP.NET website, not a web application. Is it possible to create a nuget package of that website that I can reference in another project?

Essentially my ASP.NET website contains a bunch of handler files (`.ashx`). I want to reference those files, so it would be great if I can create a nuget package for that.

Comment: why nuget package, are they going to be used by multiple project ? if they are to be used only in one project then I would simply copy them.

Comment: After copying .ashx files? How should I call a method in them? Do you know how to wire .ashx files in ASP.NET Core Web API through middleware?

Comment: I don't think you can wire .ashx files within core web API. it is nowhere mention in question that it is a web api that you want to reference. you should mention your requirements clearly in question.